# 5 Second AVI File Way Too Large

Tags: avi

Is it weird for a 5 second video rendered in Sony Vegas 13 to be 500 MB?

It has a sound file that is 15 MB and an animation that is 80 MB, is there a reason the file size is so large for this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not weird at all. You are probably rendering without any compression. Uncompressed AVI files tend to be very large.

If you are looking to lower the size try rendering in mp4 for example. When rendering in Vegas 13 there is a section called "MainConcept AVC/AAC" with a few presets to choose from that can be furthermore changed to your liking.